# BLDC motor control

Tags: arduino-uno, motor

I want to control a BLDC motor with Arduino board and a circuit with some transistors and other elements, the input of this board will be flight control. my question is that is it possible to connect a flight control with an Arduino board? if it is possible do you have any idea?

Comment: [Yes it is possible](https://www.google.com/search?&q=how+to+connect+arduino+to+flight+controller)

Comment: You should also check https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/169398/bldc-motor-without-esc and https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/355167/how-does-a-hobby-esc-drive-a-bldc-motor . Making your own ESC or " a circuit with some transistors ..." as you have said is no easy task.

Comment: You do you even want to build your own ESC? I don't think, that this will be cheaper than simply buying one.

Comment: Tnx ,i know uts better to buy a ESC but i wanna  have exprience in building a ESC  for a quad.i will make it with a arduino board and push_pull transistors in this circuit i control the arduino board with two  micro swiths but now l wanna control this with flight controller by giveing the flight control signal to arduino how can i do it?